# Modify xml_document in officer in R

Tags: r, xml, docx, officer, xml2

I have an `rdocx` and I want to manipulate something in the xml code. That's my document:

```
library(officer)

doc <- read_docx() %>%
  body_add_par("centered text", style = "centered") %>%
  slip_in_seqfield("STYLEREF 1 \\s") %>% 
  slip_in_text("\u2011") %>% 
  slip_in_seqfield(sprintf("SEQ %s \\* ARABIC \\s 1", "Table")) %>% 
  slip_in_text(str_c(": ", "My Caption")) %>% 
  body_bookmark("my_bookmark")
```

With `doc$doc_obj$get()` I can get the xml code with classes `xml_document` and `xml_node`. Now I want to replace some code, in detail I want the part with `w:bookmarkEnd` to appear later so the bookmarked part gets bigger. How can I achieve this? If I could achieve this with `str_replace` it would be awesome.

Comment: Please don't use internals, use `officer::docx_body_xml()` instead of `doc$doc_obj$get()`, unless you want to risk an unwanted breaking change :). Also, you are using `slip_in_*` that all are deprecated or defunct and should be replaced by calls to `fpar(run_...)`. About your question, I don't think you can with str_replace, but it should be ok using the documented function `officer::run_bookmark()`

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, I've hoped that you would reply to me question and I would prefer a way with `run_bookmark, too`. Do you have an idea how I can get a bookmark from the beginning until `"SEQ %s \\* ARABIC \\s 1 Table"`? I've already tried it but without any success :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `run_bookmark()` as in the following example (the manual does not state that lists are supported, I'll add that info soon):

```r
library(officer)

bkm <- run_bookmark(
  bkm = "test",
  list(
    run_word_field(field = "SEQ tab \\* ARABIC \\s"),
    ftext(" Table", prop = fp_text_lite(color = "red"))
  )
)
doc <- read_docx()

doc <- body_add_fpar(
  x = doc,
  value = fpar(bkm)
)

# how to make a reference to the bkm
doc <- body_add_fpar(
  x = doc,
  value = fpar(run_reference("test"))
)

print(doc, "zz.docx")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so so so much, you saved my whole day, really!!!